# MFC- Programmatically Disable Charms Bar

Tags: winapi, windows-8, gesture, charms-bar

I need to programmatically disable Windows 8 charms bar.
On MSDN i can find sample code to do that.
However while using that code snippet with Windows 8 SDK installed on my machine i am getting Linker error.
The code snippet can be found at [System.EdgeGesture.DisableTouchWhenFullscreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I am able to retrieve the PropertyStore pointer but when i try to set the value "PKEY_EdgeGesture_DisableTouchWhenFullscreen" i am get linker error for this property.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol is exported the following lib files.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib>findstr /m /S /c:"PKEY_EdgeGesture
isableTouchWhenFullscreen" *.*

win8\um\arm\Uuid.Lib
win8\um\x64\ehstorguids.lib
win8\um\x64\Uuid.Lib
win8\um\x86\ehstorguids.lib
win8\um\x86\Uuid.Lib
```

Did you modify your libpath?

Comment: I am able to compile it and the API works fine as expected. However it doesn't hide the already visible charms bar. Once hidden it does prevent reopening of charms bar. Any idea how already visible charms bar can be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to create(if not existed) **EdgeUI** key under:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell

and add new DWORD keys: **DisableTLcorner** & **DisableCharmsHint**

For disable:

```
DisableTLcorner = 1 
DisableCharmsHint = 1
```

For Enable change to zero or delete them:

```
DisableTLcorner = 0 
DisableCharmsHint = 0
```

All this can be easily done in MFC!!!!