# windows 8 gestures on edge of screen

Tags: winapi, windows-8, windows-runtime, desktop-application

I have a desktop application running on windows 7 and 8. We implemented gestures using WM_GESTURE to support both windows. When running on windows 8 tablet, if user try to swipe, pan etc from of the edge i.e out side the visible screen, gestures do not work. When i logged the event(messages) application receives, it shows no gesture message.

On metro apps you see menu at bottom of screen when you swipe up from outside the screen area. I want similar functionality with my desktop application. Is this possible? Does desktop app has limitation or i am missing something? I searched over but cannot find a clear cut answer positive or negative.

Further info if of any help. It is a MFC application using both VC++ and C#. Minimum supported version of windows is 7.

One more thing. Our application runs in full screen with no task bar etc, like slide show.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC- Programatically Disable Charms Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722154/mfc-programatically-disable-charms-bar)

Comment: Well not exactly. 1st, I do not want to disable charm bars as it will be disabled system wide. 2nd, i want to get this charm bar event so i can show menu like metro apps, not disable it.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself. You say you want to leave the charm gesture enabled, then you say you want to override it with your custom menu.

Comment: Ok, let me try again. When you open a metro app and swipe up from bottom to tablet, the menu to that app appears. The charm bars, in general are windows own functionality which appears on left, right, top and bottom. I do not want to disable these all functions. I just want to show my desktop application menu when user swipe from bottom of screen, like charm bar. That, i guess, will happen if i over ride the charm bar event rather than disable. Also i just want it at bottom of screen. All other sides should perform as usual. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay, there is some terminology confusion. The Charms bar is the menu that appears when you swipe from the right edge. The other edges do not invoke the Charms bar. I think what you are trying to say is that you want to leave the Charms bar alone and just have a menu for swiping from the bottom edge.

Comment: I think you got it. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: So any suggestion? Or is this even possible what i am trying to do?

Comment: I don't see a way to disable only selected edges. Not saying it doesn't exist, but I don't see it.